# bigquery, extract_table AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'dataset'

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

my question is about a code to extract a table extract a table from Bigquery and save it as a json file
.
I made my code mostly by following the gcloud tutorials on their documentation.

I couldn't implicit set my credentials, so I did it in a explicit way, to my json file. But it seems that it doesn't quite get the "Client" object by the path I took.

If anyone could clarify me how this whole implicit and explicit credential works, would help me a lot too!

I am using python 2.7 and pycharm. The code is as follows:

```
from gcloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
def bigquery_get_rows ():

    json_key = "path/to/my/json_file.json"
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(json_key)
    print("\nPeguei o Cliente\n")

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
    print(storage_client)

    #Setando ambiente
    bucket_name = 'my_bucket/name'
    print(bucket_name)
    destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'my_table_json_name.json')
    print(destination_uri)
    #dataset_ref = client.dataset('samples', project='my_project_name')
    dataset_ref = storage_client.dataset('my_dataset_name', project='my_project_id')
    print(dataset_ref)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table('my_table_to_be_extracted_name')
    print(table_ref)

    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.destination_format = (
        bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref, destination_uri, job_config=job_config)  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

bigquery_get_rows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong client object. You try to use gcs client to work with bigquery.

Instead of

```
dataset_ref = storage_client.dataset('my_dataset_name', project='my_project_id')
```

it should be:

```
bq_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(
    'path/to/service_account.json')
dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset('my_dataset_name', project='my_project_id')
```